# Date convertion in stored procedure tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

I have column of type of datetime, that I am using in my stored procedure by declaring the two local variables as `@From datetime and @To datetime`, but no matter what I do I get the error or it simply run the stored procedure without returning any records(completely blank).

```
set @mySql ='
select * from abc where (MyDATE between '''+ cast(@From as datetime) +''' and '''+ cast(@To as datetime)+''')'
```

Comment: You have to cast you local variables to varchar in order to use in a dynamic query.

Comment: How are you passing the parameters? If you pass them as typed parameters (and this is what you should do!), there is no need for casts. Datetimes are especially prone to errors due to culture/language settings...

Comment: Just saw, that you are creating dynamic SQL... Why? At least with the snippet given, this is not necessary...

Comment: @AbdulRasheed - not at all true. You can use dynamic SQL and still keep your data in variables/parameters of the appropriate type, provided you execute it using [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: @Shnugo I believe that it is intended - quite reasonably - as a minimal example, and that the *actual* code is more dynamic; personally I think it does a great job of conveying the intent without getting bogged down in unnecessary overheads.

Comment: @MarcGravell If you are right, then you are right :-) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep your data in variables of the appropriate type, whenever possible.

For instance, here you can do:

```
--@From and @To are declared previously as datetimes
set @mySql ='select * from abc where (MyDATE between @From and @To)'

--Other code that constructs/works on @mySQL

--Finally, run the dynamic sql:
EXEC sp_executesql @mySql,
                   '@From datetime,@To datetime`,
                   @From,
                   @To
```

And everything should work beautifully because you're not forcing back and forth between strings and `datetime`s, and its those *conversions* that introduce the opportunity to have formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

The only "correct" way to do this is to preserve them **as parameters** inside the dynamic SQL. For example:

```
set @mySql =N'select * from abc where MyDATE between @from and @to';

exec sp_executesql @mySql, N'@from datetime, @to datetime', @fromOuter, @toOuter;
```

This keeps them correctly typed **in the dynamic code**, and avoids both formatting concerns and SQL injection risks. Note that the names inside and outside the dynamic code do not need to match, as shown in the example above (`@from` and `@to` are the names in the dynamic code; `@fromOuter` and `@toOuter` are the names in the calling code).

Note that it doesn't matter if you pass in more parameters than you actually use (this would be pretty normal for a dynamic filtering method).

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that when you are building the Dynamic SQL, you are looking to cast your parameters as DateTime.

What you should actually do is avoid the use of casting. Set the Parameters as date time and store required values before you use them to build your dynamic SQL Statement.